# Write text with overline

Tags: excel, openxml

I know there is a formula that you can use and then execute to make a text overlined, but that looks strange when you click on that text. Using equation tools - accent and overbar works, but I am limited on font and I need to use a certain font, not Cambria Math.
Also I would like an easier way that can be then generated from code behind.

Does anyone knows how to write a text with overline in Excel?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you mean by overline?

Comment: If you want a continuous line (without gaps between certain characters) then the only way to do it is to format the top border of the cell. Of course, this means that the over-line will extend the entire width of the cell. If you want it letter-by-letter (and this will show gaps between some characters) then you do it by inserting a unicode over-line character before each display character.

Comment: This works, although I can see the line is not continuous. But for having overline only on some part of the word, I think this is the best option. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub HelloWorld()
   Dim s As String, s2 As String
   s = "HELLOWORLD"
   For i = 1 To Len(s)
      s2 = s2 & Mid(s, i, 1) & ChrW(773)
   Next i

   With ActiveCell
      .Font.Name = "Arial MS Unicode"
      .Value = s2
   End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Note I have picked a commonly available font.